# NA values in R when trying to convert to as.numeric

Tags: r, numeric

I am trying to convert a column of characters into a column of numeric values. They are already numbers but R recognizes them as characters. Every time i do this, the negative values become NAs.

I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: HI Maia. Normally this sort of thing works fine `as.numeric("-1.5")` so you'll need to include examples of what you are trying to convert. Do you have characters other than 0-9, ".", and "-" in your column?

Answer (score 0):

as.integer() should do the trick.
for example

```
a <- list('1',"2","3","4","5","-5","-1")
b <-  as.integer(a)
```

Here is a helpful link for more information - https://statisticsglobe.com/convert-character-to-numeric-in-r/

Hope this helps.